# React: Passing function to React props but giving error on accessing it in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have passed two props in two separate renders of the same component and passed one prop as a function and other as a string.
However on accessing it in the component for rendering, it says:
"props.prop1 is not a function"

This my App.js file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Test from './components/Test';

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <Test prop1={() => {return "a"}}/>
        <Test prop2="b"/>



      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

    export default App;
```

This my Test.js file:

```
import React from "react";

function Test(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="test">
        <div>Test data {props.prop1()} </div>
        <div>{props.prop2}</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared 2 `<Test>` components in your `<App>` and you are not passing `prop2` on the 2nd one:

You might want to pass them all at the same time like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import Test from './components/test';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit
          {' '}
          <code> src / App.js </code>
          {' '}
          and save to reload.
        </p>
        <Test
          prop1={() => 'a'}
          prop2="b"
        />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can we not pass it separately? As if we pass primitive data in such manner, it gives no error.

Comment: Yes, we can optionally pass them, if you not passing any props, they will be undefined, and for a function, it's basically undefined(). So you get `props.prop1 is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `prop1` and `prop2` alternatively. So you should pass both props.

If you want to pass props alternative then you can do as. Add default function(Which just invoke but won't do anything) if `prop1` is absent as

```
prop1 = () => {}
```

**1)** Should use when you want to show the `div` despite of `prop1` value

```
import React from "react";

function Test({ prop1 = () => {}, prop2 }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="test">
        <div>Test data {prop1()} </div>
        <div>{prop2}</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

**2)** If you want to hide the `div` if the `prop1` is not present then you can use `&&` as

```
import React from "react";

function Test(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="test">
        {
          props.prop1 && <div>Test data {props.prop1()} </div>
        }
        {
          props.prop2 && <div>{props.prop2}</div>
        }
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Test;
```